# Не получается связать функции. Задача: реализовать функцию, которая параметрами будет принимать два числа и возвращать НОД этих двух чисел

Tags: javascript

```js
let num1 = 12;
let num2 = 27;

function getDiv(num1, num2) { //Находит делители числа.
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

function getInt(arr1, arr2) { // сравнение элементов arr1 и arr2.
  let int = [];
  for (let elem of arr1) {
    if (inArray(elem, arr2)) {
      int.push(elem);
    }
  }
  return (int);
}

function inArray(elem, arr) { // проверяет есть ли elem в arr.
  return arr.indexOf(elem) !== -1;
}
console.log(getInt(arr1, arr2));
```

Comment: 1. А что такое тут ```for(let i = 2; i < num; i++)```  переменная num?
2. Что такое тут ```(getInt(arr1, arr2));``` arr1 и arr2? Разве вы их где-то объявили?

Может, попробуйте просто для начала вывести в консоль результаты работы каждоый функции.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```js
let num1 = 12;
let num2 = 27;

function compareArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  let commonValues = [];
  arr1.forEach(item => arr2.includes(item) ? commonValues.push(item) : false) //если нашли совпадение во втором массиве - пушим в результирующий массив
  return Math.max(...commonValues);
}

let findAllNODes = (num) => {
  let arrOfNODes = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < num + 1; i++) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
      arrOfNODes.push(i)
    }
  }

  return arrOfNODes;
}

let arrOne = findAllNODes(num1); //тут записываем результат работы функции в переменную
let arrTwo = findAllNODes(num2); // и тут
console.log(arrOne, arrTwo)

console.log(compareArrays(arrOne, arrTwo))
```